# how to get the children of OpaqueValueExpr in Clang AST

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a part of AST as the picture followed. 
[image]

The code of this BinaryOperator is:

```
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Then I use ASTVisitor to get the information of this line of code.

```
bool VisitBinaryOperator(BinaryOperator *node) {

    ObjCPropertyRefExpr *lvalue = dyn_cast<ObjCPropertyRefExpr>(node->getLHS());

    if (lvalue && \
        lvalue->isMessagingSetter() && \
        lvalue->getSetterSelector().getAsString() == "setContentMode:")
    {
        OpaqueValueExpr *rvalue = dyn_cast<OpaqueValueExpr>(node->getRHS());

        // I want to get DeclRefExpr of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit here.
    }
    return true;
}
```

I can get the `lvalue` right, but how can I get the `DeclRefExpr` at the last line of the AST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OpaqueValueExpr` holds another expression, you can access it using method `getSourceExpr()`.

Within your AST the source expression will be an implicit cast, which is not the goal. For this purpose Clang's `Expr` class has family of 'ignore' methods such as `IgnoreImpCasts` or `IgnoreParens`. These methods used to access underlying expression, like in your case.

For example, if an expression `a` has type `ImplicitCastExpr` and it holds some `b` of type `DeclRefExpr`, then `a->IgnoreImpCasts()` will return pointer to `b`. However, if we call the method on `b`, then it will return `b` itself.

Here is code to answer your question:

```
Expr *SE = rvalue->getSourceExpr()->IgnoreImpCasts();
if (DeclRefExpr *DRE = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(SE)) {
    // do you magic with DeclRefExpr here
}
```