# Iterate subtree of clang

Tags: c++, recursion, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I have detected all the places where there are assignment statements by visiting Binary Operators that are "="

From there I got the LHS and RHS by doing binaryOperator->getLHS() and getRHS() respectively

How should I go about iterating through all the nodes within the RHS.

Currently I have tried to use `Stmt::child_iterator` recursively to visit all the child nodes but it seems to only be going 1 level down.

```
bool recursiveVisit (Stmt *stmt) {
  for (Stmt::child_iterator i = stmt->child_begin(), e = stmt->child_end(); i != e; ++i) {
    Stmt *currStmt = *i;
    errs() << "Hello";
    recursiveVisit(currStmt);
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code? Some of my trees only have "Hello" printed once, it's not going any further down. Others don't even print "Hello" once at all.

Comment: child_iterator only goes one level down, or recursiveVisit only goes one level down?

Comment: I found the recurse code works but whenever it hits OpaqueValueExpr, it doesn't break down further and recurse into it's children. Is there anything special or unique about OpaqueValueExpr? @immibis

Comment: I know this is old, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586677/how-to-get-the-children-of-opaquevalueexpr-in-clang-ast) is a related question and answer to your concern about `OpaqueValueExpr`